# How to set particular Tab and get Current Tab while using TabLayout of android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-support-design

I'm referring [this](http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/) example to implement TabLayout and I'm done with it. But my problem is as per my app requirement I want to jump to perticular Tab from another activity.and also perform some action on current Tab. So can anybody tell me how to **get Current Tab** and **set particular Tab**.

Comment: pass some argument to activity to recognize which tab to select, and use setCurrentItem on view pager object.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add the tab you want to be selected first (For Example,  Tab2 is default selected).

```
actionBar.addTab(tab2);
actionBar.addTab(tab0, 0, false);
actionBar.addTab(tab1, 1, false);
```